# Difference between NestedStackedInline and NestedTabularInline

Tags: python, django, django-models

I using a *nested* model in a Django project.

---

The following snippet code is **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE

class Model_(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="This is a model")
    frequently = models.FloatField(default=1.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SubModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='0x')
    model_ = models.ForeignKey(Model_, on_delete=CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    

class Metadata(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sub_model = models.ForeignKey(SubModel, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

---

This is my **admin.py** script:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from nested_inline.admin import NestedTabularInline, NestedStackedInline,\
    NestedModelAdmin
from <djano-application-name>.models import Model_, SubModel, Metadata

class MetadataAdmin(NestedTabularInline):
    model = Metadata
    extra = 1

class SubModelAdmin(NestedStackedInline):
    model = SubModel
    inlines = [MetadataAdmin]
    extra = 1

class Model_Admin(NestedModelAdmin):
    model = Model_
    inlines = [SubModelAdmin]
    list_display = ['name']

admin.site.register(Model_, Model_Admin)
```

---

### Question:

What is the difference between `NestedStackedInline` and `NestedTabularInline` in **admin.py** script?

---

[**NOTE**]:

Versions: *Python 2.7* and *Django 1.11*

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [`django-nested-inline`](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline), It means you wanted to edit models on the same page as a parent model and add more than 1 level of children at once with the parent object in admin.

> The Django admin is just a normal Django application and you can't have a second level of inlines(nested forms) in the default Django admin.

The difference between `NestedStackedInline` and `NestedTabularInline` is just **Layout**. Indeed, both work exactly the same behind the scenes, the only difference is the template used for rendering. Check the official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects). So, picking one for your project is only a matter of preference regarding the interface layout.

This is how **NestedStackedInline** will look, each field of the model is under other.

[image]

and this is **NestedTabularInline**, each field of the model is in one line, column wise

[image]